# Create column with ranking order

Tags: sql-server, rank

is the a way i can create a new ID column (Nr) which ranks only by the column "Family" name? this is the desired output:

| Date | Letter | Family | Nr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | A | John | 1 |
| 202201 | A | John | 1 |
| 202201 | A | John | 1 |
| 202201 | A | Ruth | 2 |
| 202201 | B | Ruth | 2 |
| 202201 | B | Ruth | 2 |
| 202201 | B | Ruth | 2 |
| 202201 | B | Andrea | 3 |
| 202201 | B | Andrea | 3 |
| 202201 | B | Andrea | 3 |
| 202201 | C | Andrea | 3 |
| 202201 | C | Andrea | 3 |
| 202201 | C | John | 1 |
| 202201 | D | John | 1 |
| 202201 | D | John | 1 |

Comment: [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: What is logic by which John = 1 Ruth = 2 Andrea = 3?